# How to fix permissions errors for yeoman

Tags: node.js, permissions, yeoman-generator-angular

trying to run yo...and getting these errors. I've tried a bunch of methods to fix this..nothing worked yet.

here is what the error reads:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a closed [issue](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman.github.io/issues/282#issuecomment-64543114) on yeoman githib repo. Please refer to that discussuion for more details. You should try `chmod g+rwx /users/jeremychoi/.config/configstore/insight-yo.json` this might work in your case. More on unix permissions refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod).